# How to populate IE toolbar as a default

Tags: internet-explorer, toolbar

I have created toolbar for IE that is working fine. But I have small issue that I need to populate IE toolbar default after installation.

After Installation it's populating in IE8 properly but not in IE7 and IE9.

Please suggest me that what i will do for this solution.

Thanks in advance.